# QT Designer write tags to ui file

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qt4.7

We've created a custom QT Designer widget for our navigation.
Now.

I've created a QD Designer Extension to dynamically add Buttons to this navigation widget.
Those buttons have to be stored somehow into the ui file.

The QListWidget does this by writing "item" tags into the ui file.

How can I write tags like these into the ui file?

Comment: Are there any extensions that allow me to reproduce QListWidgets behaviour when adding items?

Comment: @JacobKrieg only use [inline code markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5910580) when it's actually code, not product names.